# ajuda no aplicativo de papel de parede?

Tags: android

Eu estou com problemas no meu aplicativo que  coloca papel de parede no celular,
na minha programação eu consegui colocar 1 imagem  e consegui colocar  o botão que  adiciona o papel de parede do aplicativo no celular,  mas eu quero por uma galerias de imagens com fotos que eu escolher, e colocar a opção de abrir a imagem e ajustar.
eu já tentei usar o método do picasa mas o picasa está aposentado e nao sei como vou fazer isso.

vou deixar meu código abaixo.

> MainActivity

```
  Button bnt;
ImageView img;


@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

    bnt = (Button) findViewById(R.id.setwall);
    img = (ImageView) findViewById(R.id.img);

    bnt.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View view) {
            WallpaperManager wallmgr = WallpaperManager.getInstance(getApplicationContext());
            try {
                wallmgr.setResource(+ R.drawable.zisa);
            } catch ( IOException e){
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
        }
    });

}
```

> activity_main.xml

```
   <Button
    android:layout_width="368dp"
    android:text="Ativar papel de parede"
    android:id="@+id/setwall"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    app:layout_constraintRight_toRightOf="parent"
    app:layout_constraintLeft_toLeftOf="parent"
    app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
    app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent"
    app:layout_constraintVertical_bias="0.814" />



<ImageView
    android:id="@+id/img"
    android:layout_width="0dp"
    android:layout_height="0dp"
    android:src="@drawable/zisa"
    app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
    app:layout_constraintHorizontal_bias="0.0"
    app:layout_constraintLeft_toLeftOf="parent"
    app:layout_constraintRight_toRightOf="parent"
    app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent"
    app:layout_constraintVertical_bias="0.0" />
```

Comment: Dá uma olhada na lib [EditPhoto](https://github.com/hoanganhtuan95ptit/EditPhoto?utm_source=android-arsenal.com&utm_medium=referral&utm_campaign=6564)

Comment: Possível duplicata de [Background para Android](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/questions/266835/background-para-android)